# Why My Opencv bm3dDenoising Function Can't Work?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, noise

In my research, I want to reduce noise in a 16-bit X-ray image. 
  I have tried implementing bm3d algorithm by this paper *An Analysis and Implementation of the BM3D Image Denoising Method*, but I failed to make it useful. It took too much memory and time, and denoised image's PSNR is not good at the same time. 
  I found that there is a bm3dDenoising function exsiting in opencv extra module xphoto.
  I have tried it too. The usage of memory and time is much lower but the PSNR has decreased! I can't believe it, I think maybe 16-bit image can only use NORM_L1 that influence the result. So I tried used 8-bit gray lena image. But it also can't work, I will show the result later.
  I can't understand why it can't work? Is there anyone has used opencv xphoto::bm3dDenoising() before and could you tell me is it my problem? Did I use wrong parameter? And how can I make it useful?

Here is my code to process lena with opencv4.7.0, Windows PC and C++ :

```cpp
int main(){
cv::Mat src = cv::imread("lena.png");
cv::cvtColor(src, src, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat noisy = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
//it is my own function to add zero mean gaussion noise with sigma = 20  
addGaussionNoise(src, noisy, 0, 20);
cv::Mat basic = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());

//I use default parameter as example
cv::xphoto::bm3dDenoising(noisy, basic, dst);

return 0;
}
```

And here is the image and PSNR result:
  This is the true lena image:
[image: lena]
  This is the noisy lena image with gaussion noise:
[image: Noisy Image]
  This is the bm3dDenoising result image:
[image: bm3dDenoising]
  PSNR of noisy image = 73.3523
  PSNR of denoising image = 73.3092

I have read some of the source code of opencv bm3dDenoising and I didn't find any problem so far.
  Could anyone tell me why my application can't work?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `bm3dDenoising`, or are you complaining that it doesn't work? Take a look at the following [sample code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xphoto/test/test_denoise_bm3d.cpp). I didn't try it... Maybe the noise you added is too strong to work with default parameters.

Comment: @Rotem Of course I want to konw how to use bm3dDenoising, and wonder why it doesn't work. I try many other parameters but none of them work. I'll see the sample, and  I never meet the same thing when I use opencv.